# PHP - Loop while 'false', stop when it is 'true'

Tags: php

I want to get tomorrow date. But if tomorrow is `Saturday` or `Sunday`. It will get date in `Monday`. It will skip Saturday and Sunday. Also if tomorrow is holiday, it will skip the date and get the next date. I have list of holiday date in my database.

I've trying this code. Suppose today is `Friday, May 24`.

```
$today = "2013-05-24";

$tommorow = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today . ' + 1 day'));
$valid = check_valid($tommorow);
while (!$valid){
    $tommorow = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today . ' + 1 day'));
    $valid = check_valid($tommorow);
    if($valid){
        break;
    }
}

function check_valid($date){
    return true;
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    $day = date('D', $timestamp);
    if ($day == "Sat" || $day == "Sun"){
        return false;
    }
    $mysql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM holiday_data WHERE date = '$date'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($mysql) >= 1){
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm using `while` clause because i assume that there is `holiday date` that appears in two or three days in a row. For example, holiday is on May 27 and 28, then tomorrow date should be in `Wednesday`.

Any ideas?
Could you help me please?

If you have another approach to achieve this, I also want to know it.

Thank you,

Comment: My code result is `$tomorrow` is `May 25`. I think the `while` clause is the problem.

Comment: I think you better use date('N') than date('D') to compare. date('N') return an integer (day number in week). It's only a start.

Comment: Your check_valid function always returns true...

Comment: Looks like you'd just end up stuck in an infinte loop, because it's constantly checking if `$tommorow` using `$today + 1 day`... which would always be the Saturday (if it was the weekend). Try using `$tommorow = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tomorrow . ' + 1 day'));`

Comment: what issue are you having? you just have to return true at the end instead of the beginning in 'check_valid' function.

Comment: @AlexKevler i change to 'N' using integer and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code, doing, what you need:

It uses DateTime class and do-while loop:

```
<?php
function not_valid($date){

      $weekday = $date->format('l');
      if ($weekday == "Saturday" || $weekday == "Sunday"){
            return true;
      }

      $str_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');

      $mysql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM holiday_data WHERE date = '$str_date'");
      if (mysql_num_rows($mysql) >= 1){
            return true;
      }

      return false;
}

$today = new DateTime("2013-05-24");
do{
      //add 1 day
      $today->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}while(not_valid($today));

print $today->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

At the beginning it is 24.05.2013 - Friday. Then it adds 1 to it. 25 and 26 are Saturday and Sunday, so it skips them and prints 2013-05-27.

Answer (score 0):

As Syjin have already said, your `check_valid()` will always return `true` because you've got an `return true;` at the beginning of your function.

Move it to the end of your function to return `true` if the function hasn't returned `false` before.

Answer (score 0):

This function checks (with your logic) if a timestamp is valid and if not searches for the next valid timestamp. it will return a timestamp of the first valid timestamp possible.

```
function getNextValidDay($timestamp) {
    $day = date('D', $timestamp);
    if ($day == "Sat" || $day == "Sun"){
        $timestamp += 60*60*24;
        return getNextValidDay($timestamp);
    }
    $mysql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM holiday_data WHERE date = '$timestamp'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($mysql) >= 1){
        $timestamp += 60*60*24;
        return getNextValidDay($timestamp);
    }
    return $timestamp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the function check_valid(). You have returned true in the very beginning of the function so it will not allow to process remaining code so it should be something like this,

```
function check_valid($date){

    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    $day = date('D', $timestamp);
    if ($day == "Sat" || $day == "Sun"){
        return false;
    }
    $mysql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM holiday_data WHERE date = '$date'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($mysql) >= 1){
       return false;
     } 
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should update/increment '+ 1 day' in each loop. change your code to be something like this

```
$today  = "2013-05-24";
$ii_day = 1;

$tommorow = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today . ' + '.($ii_day).' day'));
$valid = check_valid($tommorow);
while (!$valid){
    $ii_day++;
    $tommorow = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today . ' + '.($ii_day).' day'));
    $valid = check_valid($tommorow);
    if($valid){
        break;
    }
}
```

and then on your check_valid function, change your code a bit.

```
function check_valid($date){
    //return true;
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    $day = date('D', $timestamp);
    if ($day == "Sat" || $day == "Sun"){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $mysql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM holiday_data WHERE date = '$date'");
        if (mysql_num_rows($mysql) >= 1){
           return false;
        }
        else 
            return true;
    }
}
```

hopefully it works..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution, it's based on my working days code that I use in a couple of my projects. It uses Swedish holidays but you can adjust these to the holidays that are observed in your country. Remember that many holidays depend on the current year.

```
function next_valid_day() {
    $year = date('Y');

    $easter_date = easter_date($year);

    $holidays = array(
                      mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year),                                                     // Nyårsdagen
                      mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 6, $year),                                                     // Trettondedag jul
                      //strtotime('-3 days', $easter_date),                                             // Skärtorsdagen
                      strtotime('-2 days', $easter_date),                                               // Långfredagen
                      strtotime('-1 day', $easter_date),                                                // Påskafton
                      $easter_date,                                                                     // Påskdagen
                      strtotime('+1 day', $easter_date),                                                // Annandag påsk
                      mktime(0, 0, 0, 5, 1, $year),                                                     // 1:a maj
                      strtotime('+39 days', $easter_date),                                              // Kristi himmelsfärdsdag
                      mktime(0, 0, 0, 6, 6, $year),                                                     // Sveriges nationaldag
                      strtotime('-1 day', strtotime('next Saturday', mktime(0, 0, 0, 6, 19, $year))),   // Midsommarafton
                      mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 24, $year),                                                   // Julafton
                      mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 25, $year),                                                   // Juldagen
                      mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 26, $year),                                                   // Annandag jul
                      mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, $year)                                                    // Nyårsafton
                     );

    $valid_date = false;
    $d = 0;

    while ($valid_date === false) {
        $date = strtotime('+' . ++$d  . ' days');

        if (!in_array($date, $holidays) && !(date('N', $date) > 5)) {
            $valid_date = true;
        }
    }

    return date('Y-m-d', $date);
}

var_dump(next_valid_day());
```